# How to generate dynamic url in grails

Tags: grails, url-mapping, dynamic-url

I am stuck in grails url mapping ,my requirement is to generate dynamic url based on some text entered in Database.
Let say "category" is a field in data base ,and I enter "Mobile", then the url for the mobile should be www.abc.com/mobile.Please help me on this .

thanks,

Comment: What are the other kind of urls needed for you?

Comment: urls like www.abc.com/controller/action/id .

Comment: you mean you need default url mapping and this new category one? Is there another url mapping type?

Comment: right ,i need default as well, there is no other url mapping type rather than default and this  www.abc.com/mobile.

Answer (score 1):

URL mappings support embedded variables.

So you can define url mappings for your category controller like this

```
"/$category" (controller:"category", action="index")
```

Make sure you put this mapping at the top of other url mappings / remove the default urlmappings.

The above url mappings will map to all the urls like domain.com/mobile, domain.com/laptops etc. And the name of the variable will be available in params.

So in your controller you can get the name of the category like this

```
class Category {

  def index() {
   String categoryName = params.category //this is embedded variable in urlmappings
 }
}
```

Refer [docs](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.4/guide/theWebLayer.html#urlmappings) for more details.

Comment: @ShashikantSharma Glad to know, read more in the url mappings section in grails docs. You can accept the answer btw